# how to copy the variable into one dimesional array in tcl

Tags: tcl, ns2, jenkins-2

How do I set the single variable data into a one dimensional array in ns2 using Tool Command Language?
I have tried by using the set command for that variable and an array but it shows an error like variable not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study the Tcl documentation a bit more.

For variables, assignment looks like this:

```
set foo 99
```

(`set` *name* *value*)

For arrays, assignment looks either like this:

```
set bar(foo) 99
```

(`set` *array-name*(*member-name*) *value*)

or

```
array set bar {foo 99}
```

(`array set` *array-name* ‹*list of member-names and values*›)

You can't mix assignment modes. If `abc` is the name of an array and `def` is the name of a variable, the wrong mode of assignment will give you these errors:

```
% set abc 99
can't set "abc": variable is array

% set def foo 99
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"

% set def(foo) 99
can't set "def(foo)": variable isn't array
```

You need to keep your variables and your arrays separate and use the correct invocations at all times.

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm)